# Understanding rules under the phaser3-project-template

Tags: webpack

Within the webpack.config.js file for the [phaser3-project-template](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template) what does `vert` and `frag` mean when it comes to processing rules in this template?  I was told to ask the question here and not on github.

```
  module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: [ /\.vert$/, /\.frag$/ ],
            use: 'raw-loader'
          }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions, they mean extensions. What extensions to match and apply this loader.